# Why is printing the return value of a function showing <function ... at 0x...>?

Tags: python

When I print the value that my function returns, it shows strange characters.

If I print the value inside the function, I obtain the right value:

```
0.653594771242
```

If I print the value that the function returns, I get:

```
function alpha at 0x05870630
```

```
def alpha(v1,v2):

    a=(v1,v2)
    b=1/sum(a)
    print(b)
    return b

alpha(0.817,0.713)

print(alpha)
```

Comment: You could also assign the value that is returned from the function into a variable `my_value=alpha(0.817,0.713)` then `print(my_value)` which might avoid confusion in the future?

Comment: It seems that you expect `print(alpha)` to fetch the value that was returned by the previous call `alpha(0.817,0.713)`.  That is not how it works.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you are printing an object i.e a function.

Functions in python are objects.

If you want to print the value returned by the function, you need to *call* the function and print out the return value:

```
print(alpha(0.817,0.713))
```

Answer (score 2):

This way would probably make more sense to you.

```
def alpha(v1,v2):

    a=(v1,v2)
    b=1/sum(a)
    print(b)
    return b

result = alpha(0.817,0.713)

print(result)
```

This way the function is returning the value to result then you are simply printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
print(alpha)
```

you need to write

```
print(alpha(0.817,0.713))
```