# Why is print returning an address instead of a function's return value?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print this function's return value but it just shows the address of the function.

```
def eligible(age, lingo, language):
    return "Eligible!" if(int(age) in range(25, 46)) and (lingo=='ingles') and (language=='python') else "Not Eligible!"

age=input("What's your age?: ")
language=input("What language do you speak?: ")
planguage=input("What programing language do you use?: ")
eligible(age, language, planguage)

print(eligible)
```

Comment: What else did you expect when printing a function?

Comment: `myresult = eligible(...)`  `print(myresult)`   (or just `print(eligible(...))`)

Comment: @tkausl judging by the question, seems OP expects it to print the value returned by the last invocation (and this does not happen in Python, of course)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is printing the return value of a function showing <function ... at 0x...>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196172/why-is-printing-the-return-value-of-a-function-showing-function-at-0x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python anything is an object, this includes functions.
When you print a function, you get the address of that function.

As you want your `eligible` function to return a string, you need to store the result in a variable or put the function call inside your `print` function:

```py
res = eligible(age, language, planguage)
print(res)
print(eligible(age, language, planguage))
```

Comment: Just tried this, and it worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last line and put `eligible(age, language, planguage)` in a `print` statement.

```py
def eligible(age, lingo, language):
    return "Eligible!" if(int(age) in range(25, 46)) and (lingo=='ingles') and (language=='python') else "Not Eligible!"

age=input("What's your age?: ")
language=input("What language do you speak?: ")
planguage=input("What programing language do you use?: ")
print(eligible(age, language, planguage)) # Print Statement here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly change the last line of your code :

```
def eligible(age, lingo, language):
    return "Eligible!" if(int(age) in range(25, 46)) and (lingo=='ingles') and (language=='python') else "Not Eligible!"

age=input("What's your age?: ")
language=input("What language do you speak?: ")
planguage=input("What programing language do you use?: ")
print(eligible(age, language, language))
```

Hope this will help you, thankyou!